Modeling a Reaction Wheel in SolidWorks (without Force/Torque Manager)
I am trying to simulate the effect of transferring the torque of a reaction wheel to a pendulum.
The design is simple: support, lever and wheel.
Mechanical connections: coincidence and concentricity.
I was able to create this effect only with the help of Force Property Manager, the result is shown in the figure below.

Problem: this method is not suitable, because this torque is not converted into SimMechanics! And without it, the wheel simply rotates, but the pendulum lever does not move, i.e. there is no torque transfer and the reaction torque on the lever does not arise!
Question: is it possible to build connections in such a way that the reaction torque arises only due to mechanical mates and constraints, and it is possible to use only the Motor in the SW?
